# I was wondering how I would put the arrays I have into a textView

Tags: java, android, arrays

Here is the code I have after doing some work. How do I put the three arrays into a textview that will display on my phone. I basically have to create random numbers in an array, add them up and that's the third array.

```
private int[] arrayOne =  new int[5], arrayTwo = new int[5], arrayThree = new int[5];

public int randomNumbers(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(20) -10;  
}

public void generateArrays(){
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
        arrayOne[i] = randomNumbers();
        arrayTwo[i] = randomNumbers();    
    }
}

public void arraySum(){
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++){
        int temp = arrayOne[i] + arrayTwo[i];
        if (temp < 0) temp = 0;
            arrayThree[i] = temp;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You want to display third array in textview?

Comment: Not clear what you want? Do you want to show the values from the 3rd arrays in your app? If it is the case, a ListView seems more reasonable. Otherwise you can use 5 TextViews.

Comment: I want to display the arrays so that the first  and second array is a set of random numbers from -10 to 10. Then the third array to be a sum of the first 2 arrays. For example if the first array produces a -2 and the second array produces 7, the third array should produce a 5. If the number (from the first 2 arrays),  when added up, equals a negative number then the third array should produce 0. I was just wondering how do I assign the arrays to the textView so that when i run the app all these steps happen. When I run the app now nothing shows up. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Code what you had provided doesn't use TextView. So, we can only guess what you want to show. Perhaps something like this:

```
  public String arraySum(){
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++){
            int temp = arrayOne[i] + arrayTwo[i];
            if (temp < 0) temp = 0;
            arrayThree[i] = temp;
            sb.append(arrayOne[i]).append("+").append(arrayTwo[i]);
            sb.append("=").append(temp).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();    
    }
...
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
test.setText(arraySum());
```